# Rails 4: Query with optional joins

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I've got the following classes. They work the same way: a person can be a guardian, employee and student in many schools, and they also have one user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guardians
  has_many :employee
  has_many :students
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :school
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :school
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :school
end
```

How could I retrieve all users which belong to a specific school in just one query? To get all users which are employees, for example, I could execute (using the `squeel` gem):

```
User.joins { person.employees }.where { person.employees.school_id == school_id }
```

I just don't know what query to write to include all three cases. Thanks for your help